# item in RecyclerView doesn't receive onFling event, instead recyclerview scrolls

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, exoplayer, motionevent

I have a video player, texts, images in RecyclerView item (think social media post). Whenever user swipes left or right on video, I want to seek forward or backward the video.
I have achieved that by setting the following touch listener to my video player view :

```
public abstract class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context context) {
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
    }

    public abstract void onSwipeLeft();
    public abstract void onSwipeRight();
    public abstract void onSingleTap();

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            onSingleTap();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            float distanceX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            float distanceY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY) && Math.abs(distanceX) > SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (distanceX > 0)
                    onSwipeRight();
                else
                    onSwipeLeft();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't always work as recyclerview or something gets in the way and whenever I swipe, only onDown is called in my listener and recyclerview scrolls.

How can I have my video player get fling motion first without other views intercepting it?

Comment: I'm having the same challenge. Any solution?